# How do you create a time class with derived classes for watch, timer, and stopwatch?

Tags: class, inheritance, time, timer, stopwatch

My instructions are:

Create a time class and have derived classes for watch, timer, and stopwatch. 
You should create functionality to ask the user whether they want to use a watch, timer, or stopwatch. 
You have complete latitude in your implementation of the functionality.
An example: I select a timer.  You ask for how long the time should run.  Then have the time print the time by seconds until the time has been reached.

I have no idea where to begin here. I haven't worked with time in C++ yet.

Comment: To be honest, that sounds like a really bad design to start with, so it's hard to give advice on how best to do it. It's an awful example of inheritance. Unfortunately if this is an assignment, you may have limited options - but if you can possibly choose a different assignment, I would do so.

Comment: I can't do another assignment. I'm already late turning this assignment in and I absolutely cannot just not turn it in. I have no idea what to do.

Comment: I would speak to your teacher/professor/whatever then. As I said before, it would be very hard to help with such a badly-designed assignment.